# Have a webpart in a Page layout get filter value from column value

Tags: list, filter

I'm new with SharePoint but I feel like I'm catching on pretty well.  I'm creating a new page layout and I plan to put a list webpart in the right column.  The list webpart will be filtered using the current view settings on a column called "Functional Area".  Each page that will use this page layout has a value in the functional area column.  Right now I have manual typed in the functional area into the current view so for instance it is set to "Show the items when column -> Functional Area -> is equal to -> "Testing".

Here is my question and what makes it complicated.  I would like the webpart  current view filter to automatically pull in the value for "Functional Area" of the page that the person is on and have the list webpart only show pages that has the same value in the functional area column as the current page being viewed.

Is this possible?  I'm asking because if not than I have to tell each manager to go into the webpart and change the filter value when they create a page for their group and I don't want them to have to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: How do you determine the value of the "Functional Area" column for the current page?

Comment: When the page was created the user has to select from a predetermined selection of functional areas in the page properties. It is a required column field.  Basically I want the we part list to only show the other pages from the list that have the same functional area column selection as the page they are on. Kinda like a legend of other pages from the same area but I don't want the user to have to select it ever time but be based on the page they are on.

Comment: I wanted to explain this a little better.  So in my page layout I've inserted a Pages Data View which will show the pages on my site.  I've required that each page being created on my site has a required column called "Functional Area" that must be selected from a list when saving the page.  I want to pass the value of this custom column (Functional Area) to the Pages Data View so it will only show it will filter and only show the pages that have the "Functional Area" column value that is the same as the value for the page the user is on.  I hope that helps explain it better.

Comment: Yes, that helps. So what you've inserted is a data view web part or a list view web part?

Comment: Well I'm not sure how to answer that.  I'm working in SharePoint Designer modifying the page layout.  Here is what I did.  On the page layout in SharePoint designer I hit Insert->Data View->Pages (under the Document Libraries).  In designer if you go to Insert->Webpart I don't see a Pages selection like you see when you do it from the front end editor so I figured the Data View was how you had to do it when changing the page layout in Designer.  I was then going to do conditional formatting on the data view but I'm not sure how to make it filter based on the current pages column value

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve this problem using a Content Query webpart and a Page value token.  Instead of using the Data view I switched to a Content Query webpart and selected the page list in my subsite in the properties of the Content Query webpart.  Then in the same properties area I set the filter values to the column I wanted to filter on "Functional Area" and in the value I put the following Page value token [PageFieldValue: Functional Area].  This returns the pages of the list in the subsite that have the same "Functional Area" value of the page I am currently on.  Works flawlessly and can be used on any site without messing with the GUIDs and ListIDs manually in the Page Layout in SharePoint designer.

Hopefully this helps someone else.